# Which whiteSpace option to use for long links?

Tags: css, whitespace

I have this page: https://tikex.com/hu/buyTicket/elektik-tourist-2022

In mobile the last Google link is not broken, so it stretch over the page. I use `pre-wrap` but I do not know which other I hsould use instead to break it.

```js
<p className={'p_1'} style={{ whiteSpace: 'pre-wrap', maxWidth: '80vw' }}>
    {buyTicketData?.description}
</p>
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should Try

```
word-break: break-all;
```

Like this:

```
<p className={'p_1'} style={{ wordBreak: 'break-all', maxWidth: 
'80vw' }}>
{buyTicketData?.description}
</p>
```